# "No Python at '"C:\Users" on two computers

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I'm trying tu use two computers to use vscode. I created a venv on the first one, the venv is in my drive. I was able to activate the venv from the drive on the second computer but when running a script I got the above error message.

By doing research on internet I found that I should change the PATH in the pyvenv.cfg file and that's what I have done but after reloading VScode I still have the same error.

My pyvenv.cfg file :

```
# home = C:\Users\Caracole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311 # Caracole
home = C:\Users\damien.daubricourt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311 # Setec

include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.11.1

# executable = C:\Users\Caracole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe # Caracole
executable = C:\Users\damien.daubricourt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe # Setec

# command = C:\Users\Caracole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m venv C:\Users\Caracole\My Drive\Programmation\Python\.venv\ZDT # Caracole
command = C:\Users\damien.daubricourt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m venv G:\Mon Drive\Programmation\Python\.venv\ZDT # Setec
```

The error code :

> No Python at
> '"C:\Users\Caracole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311 #
> Caracole\python.exe'

I changed the path in pyvenv.cfg file and was expecting to solve the error.

Comment: Python virtual environments are not meant to be moved or renamed. I recommend you to re-create the virtual environments from scratch. The `pyvenv.cfg` file is not meant to be edited or manipulated. You added comments, but I am not sure that comments are allowed in this file. Look at the error message very carefully!

Comment: Have you choose the python interpreter? If you choose the `.venv` interpreter, it should not have the same error message the second time.